# What is the best way to check if System.Collections.Generic.List<T> is updated (C# 4.0)?

Tags: .net, list, c#-4.0, fody-propertychanged

I need to identify if a list is updated (item added/removed). I need to use `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`, I cannot use `ObservableCollection` for this (and subscribe to it's `CollectionChanged` event).

Here is what I have tried so far:

I am using `Fody.PropertyChanged` instead of implementing `INotifyPropertyChangedEvent` - [Fody Property Changed on GitHub](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged)

```
[AlsoNotifyFor("ListCounter")]
public List<MyClass> MyProperty
{get;set;}

public int ListCounter {get {return MyProperty.Count;}}

//This method will be invoked when ListCounter value is changed
private void OnListCounterChanged()
{
   //Some opertaion here
}
```

Is there any better approach. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong, so that I can improve.

Comment: *Why* can you not use `ObservableCollection<T>`? Whatever you do here is likely to be reinventing the wheel, in a less-than-optimal way.

Comment: I know it is simple to implement with ObservableCollection<T>, but in case List is there any way to make it work like ObservableCollection<T>.

Comment: No - if you could use `List<T>` like `ObservableCollection<T>`, the latter wouldn't need to exist...

Comment: As @JonSkeet tried to ask, **why** can't you use `ObservableCollection<T>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use extension methods:

```
    var items = new List<int>();
    const int item = 3;
    Console.WriteLine(
        items.AddEvent(
            item,
            () => Console.WriteLine("Before add"),
            () => Console.WriteLine("After add")
        )
        ? "Item was added successfully"
        : "Failed to add item");
```

Extension method itself.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool AddEvent<T>(this List<T> items, T item, Action pre, Action post)
    {
        try
        {
            pre();
            items.Add(item);
            post();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that I assume you would use "AddEvent" instead "Add" wherever you need to track add event. You did not mention if event should be thrown before or after add item, so I included both. Overwriting existing implementation would be bad. Note Jon Skeet comment : "No - if you could use List<T> like ObservableCollection<T>, the latter wouldn't need to exist...".